# How to bind to a custom property in my entity partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, eval

I have an entity class with a `MailingState` property.  I want to do some manipulation of that value in another property, so I added:

```
public string MailingStateAbbreviation
{
    get { return getStateAbbreviation(MailingState); }
    set { MailingState = value; }
}
```

However, in a `DetailsView` `EditItemTemplate`, the following fails when I try to submit the edit form:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMailingState" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddlAllStates"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="StateAbbreviation"
        DataValueField="StateAbbreviation"
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MailingStateAbbreviation") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I get this error:

> A property named 'MailingStateAbbreviation' was not found on the entity during an insert, update, or delete operation. Check to ensure that properties specified as binding expressions are available to the data source.

If I change `Bind` to `Eval` on the `SelectedValue`, the form submits fine but the `MailingState` property is not updated.  How can I bind form controls to custom properties on my entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I would prefer a more declarative approach that doesn't involve handling events, this worked.  I added an `OnItemUpdating` handler to the `DetailsView`, implemented as follows:

```
protected void dvOrg_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var view = (DetailsView)sender;
    var mailStateDdl = (DropDownList)view.FindControl("ddlMailingState");
    e.NewValues["MailingState"] = mailStateDdl.SelectedValue;
}
```

In my .aspx, I had this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMailingState" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddlAllStates"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataTextField="StateAbbreviation"
        DataValueField="StateAbbreviation"
        SelectedValue='<%# Eval("MailingStateAbbreviation") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```